# What specifically does the AOSP repo tool checkout for each git repo?

Tags: git, android-source, repository

Using the "repo" (written in python) tool from AOSP, when you use its "sync" command, according to other answers I've read here such as ([How does the Android repo manifest repository work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149725/how-does-the-android-repo-manifest-repository-work?rq=1)) it will checkout the branch specified in the manifest for that git repo.

But that does **not** match with what I actually see when going into one of the git local repos, where I get:

```
aosp@aosp:/aosp/android-x86-jb42/bionic$ git branch 
* (no branch)
```

and .git/HEAD contains a SHA instead of a ref to the branch ref path.
So to me it looks more like being on a detached head but again if I manually do that (checkout a specific commit) the result of git branch will display the sha1 in the output, not just "(no branch)" as above.

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

repo sync is equivalent to below git commands :

```
 git remote update
 git rebase origin/branch
```

If you want to check what commands it runs internally then use --trace with repo command. e.g.

```
repo --trace sync
```